# How to create responsive grid in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, responsive-design, flutter-layout

What is **best practice** to make a flutter app **responsive**? 
In the code below is a **StraggeredGridView** with **hardcoded values**.

Should I write a method that is calculating the values, depending on the screen size, or are there any other ways to do so?

Thanks for your help!

```
  StaggeredGridView.count(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    crossAxisSpacing: 20,
    mainAxisSpacing: 20,
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 20),
    //shrinkWrap: true,
    children: <Widget>[
      _buildTile(
          Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Material(
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(123, 228, 193, 0.5),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'assets/siren.png',
                      height: 40,
                    ),
                  )),
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0)),
              Text('NOTRUF', style: tileFontStyle),
            ]),
          ),),
```

Comment: use layoutbuilder instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`layoutBuilder` as @Abbas.M mentioned is a possibility What you also can use is [mediaQuery](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html)

```
    var deviceData = MediaQuery.of(context); 
    var screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    var deviceOrientation = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;

    if (screenSize.width > oneColumnLayout) {
      ...
    } else {
      ...
    }
```

like the device data, screen size, or orientation, but also animations and other stuff this really helps.

Answer (score 16):

You can make it responsive just like how you do it in CSS.

Use mathematics! but how?

Use MediaQuery width to play with the crossAxisCount attribute:

```
crossAxisCount:(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width ~/ 250).toInt()
```

---

**Extra useful tip:**

Case you need to control **Min / Max** count you can import math library and use **min / max** functions.

Example:

```
import 'dart:math';


/// Inside widget build insert following variables

final currentCount = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width ~/ 250).toInt();

final minCount = 4;

...

// Automatically select whichever is greater

crossAxisCount: max(currentCount, minCount);


// Automatically select whichever is less

crossAxisCount: min(currentCount, minCount);
```

Comment: math is awesome

Comment: Simple & working!!! Thanks a ton a man!!

Answer (score 9):

use [responsive_grid](https://pub.dev/packages/responsive_grid) package

it works like the Bootstrap grid system

Answer (score 3):

What I've been doing lately is that I get the dimensions of an app when it starts and store them as constants that i use all over the app. check out [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-effectively-scale-ui-according-to-different-screen-sizes-2cb7c115ea0a) as i found it very helpful.

You can also use some widgets that does the scaling on their own like `layoutBuilder` more on that [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Creating-Responsive-Apps)

Answer (score 3):

Use the MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.landscape on crossAxisCount. Then use ternary operator or if/else statement to state crossAxisCount values. See example below. Worked for me.

```
crossAxisCount: (MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.landscape) ? 4 : 2
```